# ValueError: time data '25-08-2012 00:00' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M' (match

Tags: pandas, datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import numPy as np # For mathematical calculations
import matplotlib.pyplot as pit # For plotting graphs
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime # To access datetime
from pandas import Series # To work on series
import warnings # To ignore the warnings warnings.filterwarnings("ignore" )

train=pd.read_csv( "train.csv")
train.head()
```

Data:

```
    ID  Datetime    Count
0   0   25-08-2012 00:00    8
1   1   25-08-2012 01:00    2
2   2   25-08-2012 02:00    6
3   3   25-08-2012 03:00    2
4   4   25-08-2012 04:00    2
```

I am trying to convert the date format above :

```
train['New_date'] = pd.to_datetime(train.Datetime, format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')
```

But I get :

> ValueError: time data '25-08-2012 00:00' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M' (match)

I read many similar questions in the forum but I am still stuck.

Comment: There is no double `d` like `%d-%d` ? is necessary `%d-%m`

Comment: Helpful feedback: please always use the formatting tools provided. This was nearly unreadable before I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap `d` with `m`, because format of datetimes is `DD-MM-YYY HH:MM`:

```
train['New_date'] = pd.to_datetime(train.Datetime, format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's true. There is no month 25

(swap either your data or your format string around so that they agree. Right now one is DMY and the other is MDY)

Comment: Thank you very much for being vigilant and for your speedy answer. Really thanks.

Comment: No probs. I caught an odd thing by the way; I was gonna edit a typo in jezrael's Answer and it looked like you'd edited another error message into the bottom of his answer and a thanks into the reason for editing - of it wasn't some strange glitch in the matrix, I would recommend that you instead ask a new question if the error has now changed to be something else. Questions that start out as one problem and end up as another through a series of edits are not very useful in the way SO wants to be a wiki(and moving goalposts are very annoying). New problems should always be put in new questions